# Can I use ternary on chartjs options, especially on legend?

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm very confused looking for ways to make a legend only appear in a few conditions. For example, like the example below.

```
options: {
        responsive: true,
        legend: chartType === 'pie'?{
            display: true
        }:{display: false}
}
```

Comment: `legend: { display: ( chartType === 'pie' ) }` Use the correct syntax.

Comment: Why not `{ display: chartType === 'pie' }`?

Comment: @Shilly Thank youuu, its very good solution